# Unable to preseed user creation and partitioning with ubuntu netboot 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, preseed, pxe

Okay, so I am trying to automate the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the netboot image for use on our virtual machines (I'm using VirtualBox if that matters). I'm not sure if the virtual machine is the source of the problem, but I can't see why it would be. It preseeds everything except for creating a user account and writing to the partition. I wouldn't be surprised if I was doing the partitioning stuff the wrong way. I would like for it to simply take up all available space and automatically partition. With the user stuff however, I am incredibly confused. When I ran an install from an unseeded netboot image and got a preseed file using `debconf-get-selections --installer` and `debconf-get-selections`, I noticed that instead of `d-i passwd/[whatever]` user creation was done using `user-setup-udeb`. Changing from `d-i` did nothing to help.

Let me know if you need any more information. Here is my preseed file.

preseed.cfg:

```
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

### Network configuration
# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Just in case our DHCP server is busy.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostnameoc
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

### Mirror settings
# Alternatively: by default, the installer uses CC.archive.ubuntu.com where
# CC is the ISO-3166-2 code for the selected country. You can preseed this
# so that it does so without asking.
d-i mirror/http/mirror select us.archive.ubuntu.com

### Account setup
# Skip creation of a root account (normal user account will be able to
# use sudo).
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false
d-i passwd/make-user boolean true


# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string master
d-i passwd/username string master
# Normal user's password, either in clear text
#d-i passwd/user-password password [redacted]
#d-i passwd/user-password-again password [redacted]
# or encrypted using an MD5 hash.
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password [redacted]
# Create the first user with the specified UID instead of the default.
#d-i passwd/user-uid string 1010

# The installer will warn about weak passwords. If you are sure you know
# what you're doing and want to override it, uncomment this.
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

# The user account will be added to some standard initial groups. To
# override that, use this.
#d-i passwd/user-default-groups string audio cdrom video

# Set to true if you want to encrypt the first user's home directory.
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string America/Los_Angeles

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda

# The presently available methods are:
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string regular

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

# For LVM partitioning, you can select how much of the volume group to use
# for logical volumes.
#d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /usr, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# If you just want to change the default filesystem from ext3 to something
# else, you can do that without providing a full recipe.
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

### Base system installation


### Apt setup
# You can choose to install restricted and universe software, or to install
# software from the backports repository.
#d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
#d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
#d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
# Uncomment this if you don't want to use a network mirror.
#d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
# Select which update services to use; define the mirrors to be used.
# Values shown below are the normal defaults.
#d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
#d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
#d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu

# Additional repositories, local[0-9] available
#d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string \
#       http://local.server/ubuntu squeeze main
#d-i apt-setup/local0/comment string local server
# Enable deb-src lines
#d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
# URL to the public key of the local repository; you must provide a key or
# apt will complain about the unauthenticated repository and so the
# sources.list line will be left commented out
#d-i apt-setup/local0/key string http://local.server/key

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, lubuntu-desktop

# Individual additional packages to install
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential tftp-hpa ipmitool htop mc software-properties-common python-apt python-pycurl python-setuptools
# Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
# Allowed values: none, safe-upgrade, full-upgrade
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade

# Language pack selection
d-i pkgsel/language-packs multiselect en

# No language support packages
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false

# Policy for applying updates. May be "none" (no automatic updates),
# "unattended-upgrades" (install security updates automatically), or
# "landscape" (manage system with Landscape).
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades

# Verbose output and no boot splash screen
d-i debian-installer/quiet  boolean false
d-i debian-installer/splash boolean true

### Boot loader installation
# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# Wait for two seconds in grub
d-i grub-installer/timeout string 2

# Use the following option to add additional boot parameters for the
# installed system (if supported by the bootloader installer).
# Note: options passed to the installer will be added automatically.
d-i debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string vga=normal nomodeset audit=0 \
intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=1 cgroup_enable=memory \
swapaccount=1

### Finishing up the installation
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

#### Advanced options
### Running custom commands during the installation
# d-i preseeding is inherently not secure. Nothing in the installer checks
# for attempts at buffer overflows or other exploits of the values of a
# preconfiguration file like this one. Only use preconfiguration files from
# trusted locations! To drive that home, and because it's generally useful,
# here's a way to run any shell command you'd like inside the installer,
# automatically.

# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
# This command is run immediately before the partitioner starts. It may be
# useful to apply dynamic partitioner preseeding that depends on the state
# of the disks (which may not be visible when preseed/early_command runs).
#d-i partman/early_command \
#       string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
# This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
# still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
# directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
# packages and run commands in the target system.
#d-i preseed/late_command string in-target tftp 172.16.0.1 -c get postpreseed.sh; \
#    in-target chmod +x postpreseed.sh; \
#    in-target /bin/bash -x postpreseed.sh; \
#    in-target rm -f postpreseed.sh;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, upon looking at DEBCONF logs, I realized nothing was getting preseeded and my setting of debconf_priority to critical made it seem like stuff was getting preseeded. What I didn't realize was that the preseed/file boot param actually tried to get the file from the disk of the client, not from the server.

Short answer: I'm dumb.